# Size and weight of DC-DC vs DC-AC at equivalent powers

Tags: dc-dc-converter, inverter, high-voltage, high-power, dc-ac

I am looking at designing two power systems for a project and was wondering, at equivalent power, let's say 10kW, what is the system that is easier to design, can be smaller in volume and lighter in weight: a DC-DC converter (63V - 37.5V to fixed 430V) or a DC - AC (63V - 37.5V to 230V AC at 50Hz)?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think definitely DC-DC, since a lightweight DC-AC converter will almost certainly be synthesizing the AC waveform using a boost converter anyway. To put it another way, the only thing easier about AC is that it works with transformers, but transformers have a terrible power to weight ratio so you probably won't use one anyway.

Comment: DC/DC less conditions to consider! less complex control. Can easier be made smaller due to more fixed operation conditions due to no AC